# Local Storage in HTML5

Tags: html, local-storage

I am saving a value in the local storage (html 5) in page 1 and then when i go to page 2, the values in the localstorage are gone. Could you please let me know what could be the issue?

Editing

I am actually using the following functions to set the data on the local storage

```
function set(key, data) 
{ 
     localStorage.setItem(key, data); 
} 
function get(key) 
{ 
     return localStorage.getItem(key); } 
function remove(key) { 
     localStorage.removeItem(key); } 
function clear() { 
     localStorage.clear(); 
}
```

I have issues getting it to work on Firefox and dont have any issues on Chrome. This looks like an entirely different issue.
Thanks and Regards
Abishek R Srikaanth

Comment: Can you *please* provide code? What browser are you using? Not all browsers support LocalStorage yet. Please provide more information.

Comment: page1 and page2 are served under the same domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provide enough detail to troubleshoot this properly, but check these things out:

1. Are you previewing your design locally (e.g. via the file:// protocol), or are you on a proper web server? Only http:// requests will work accurately for you
2. Local storage and Web SQL storage work by reference to the originating domain or IP address (again why point #1 is important): is your second page still in scope?
3. What happens when you go back to page 1? Do the values re-appear?